# Overloading << operator results in no output

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, output

I am not sure if I am correctly overloading the `<<` operator. The following code compiles without problem but does not produce the expected output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const matrix<T> &A)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii << A.size(1); ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < A.size(2); jj++)
        {
            out << A(ii,jj) << " ";
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    matrix<double> A = {{1.0, 2.0},{1.0,-1.0}};
    cout << "\"" << A << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The only output is:
`""`

**Matrix.h**

```
template<class T>
class matrix
{
public:
    matrix(int rows, int cols);
    matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>>& lst);
    T& operator()(int i, int j);
    T operator()(int i, int j) const;
    int size(int n) const;

private:
    int mRows;
    int mCols;
    std::vector<T> mData;
};

template<class T>
matrix<T>::matrix(int rows, int cols)
: mRows(rows),
mCols(cols),
mData(rows * cols)
{
}

template<class T>
matrix<T>::matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T> >& lst)
    : matrix(lst.size(), lst.size() ? lst.begin()->size() : 0)
{
    int ii = 0, jj = 0;
    for(const auto& l : lst)
    {
        for(const auto& v : l)
        {
            mData[ii*mCols + jj] = v;
            jj++;
        }
        jj = 0;
        ii++;
    }
}

template<class T>
T& matrix<T>::operator()(int i, int j)
{
    return mData[i*mCols + j];
}

template<class T>
T matrix<T>::operator()(int i, int j) const
{
    return mData[i*mCols + j];
}

template<class T>
int matrix<T>::size(int n) const
{
    if(n == 1)
    {
        return mRows;
    }
    else if(n == 2)
    {
        return mCols;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you also overload operator()(int,int)?

Comment: @jpm if `operator ()` wasn't overloaded, it wouldn't compile, but it's stated that the code DOES compile.

Comment: My bad. I guess it's also silly to ask if 1 and 2 are the correct values to give to size() (an enum would propbably be better), and if size fails loudly or quietly on invalid input.

Comment: @jpm I added a simplified version of `Matrix.h`, but it appears my problem was just a silly typo.

Comment: @OSE Glad it was a simple fix. Still, you should really consider using an enum type for size (and/or fail loudly for invalid values). Alternately, provide separate width and height methods (or rows and columns).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first for loop, you have:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii << A.size(1); ii++)
                   ^
```

That should be a single `<` character:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < A.size(1); ii++)
                   ^
```

The reason why it wasn't doing anything is because the original loop resulted in a condition of `0 << A.size(1)`, which is `0`, or `false`; thus, the outer loop is never executed.

Comment: Wow, I've read the code twice trying to answer and I missed that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe that I missed that.